# Unknown error message when attempting to find MLE in R

Tags: r, mle

I'm trying to find the MLE of distribution whose pdf is specified as 'mixture' in the code. I've provided the code below that gives an error of 
"Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'"

"claims" is the dataset im using. I tried the same code with just the first two values of "claims" and encountered the same problem, so for a reproducible example the first two values are    1536.77007  and   1946.92409.

The limits on the parameters of the distribution is that 0<.p.<1 and a>0 and b>0, hence the lower and upper bounds in the MLE function. Any help is much appreciated.

```
#create mixture of two exponential distribution
mixture<-function(x,p,a,b){
  d<-p*a*exp(-a*x)+(1-p)*b*exp(-b*x)
  d
  }


#find MLE of mixture distribution 
LL <- function(p,a,b) {
       X = mixture(claims,p,a,b)
      #
      -sum(log(X))
   }

mle(LL, start = list(p=0.5,a=1/100,b=1/100),method = "L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0,0,0), upper=c(1,Inf,Inf))
```

edit: Not really sure why dput(), but anyway,

```
#first two values of claims put into dput() (the actual values are above)
dput(claims[1:2])
c(307522.103, 195633.5205)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `dput()` applied to a minimal data set.

Comment: at least one of your claims numbers is so large that `b*exp(-b*x)` and `a*exp(-a*x)` both underflow to zero for your initial parameter values of a=b=1/100, so your likelihood is zero , so the log-likelihood is `-Inf` ... PS the values of the first two claims are stated differently in the text and in the code?